# How to dynamically change margin-top of a div dependent on another fixed div using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am aware there are variable posts on here answering regarding my problem. But I am not sure if there's one using only css and not jQuery. If anyone is aware to resolve it using css do tell me.

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
}

.myDiv2 {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-top: 100px;
  /* This is fixed not dependent on First Div's Height */
}
```

```html
<h1>The div element</h1>
<!--Div that needs to be static while the content can scroll below it-->
<div class="myDiv">
  <h2>This is a heading in a div 1 element</h2>
  <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv2">
  <h2>This is a heading in a div 2 element</h2>
  <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

<p>This is some text outside the div element.</p>
```

Comment: Why do you need the first div to be `fixed` for this layout?

Comment: because it'll be a banner suggesting info, i'll keep it fixed below a navbar

Comment: Why can't be in normal flow below navbar? Is the problem keeping it there despite scroll?

Comment: No the problem is the content within the banner might keep increasing or decreasing height. So the height of first fixed div is variable which is why I want to set margin top on the next div dynamic based on the variable height of first div.

Comment: You haven't explained why the div must be in "fixed" position. You have a set idea that it must be fixed and you're trying to work around it. I'm trying to understand what condition required it to be fixed

Comment: Ah yeah! My apologies. I'd put a layout but its confidential so i tried replicating the same situation with these two divs. I hope you understand my problem

Comment: I want to keep the first div static without scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If scrolling is the only problem, you can use [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) instead of `position: fixed`. It is positioned based on normal flow so you wouldn't have to manually set a margin for the content below.

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  width: 100vw;
}

.myDiv2 {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  <!-- This is fixed not dependent on First Div's Height-->

}

#long {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<h1>The div element</h1>

<div class="myDiv">
  <h2>This is a heading in a div 1 element</h2>
  <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv2">
  <h2>This is a heading in a div 2 element</h2>
  <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

<p id="long">This is some text outside the div element.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you want to put dynamically margin to child div, but I have one solution: fixed div is called Parent div and other div is called child div,
Put margin-bottom in Parent div, For example:

```
/*  CSS Code  */
.myDiv {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

Hope so it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a solution that changes the margin-top of .myDiv2 according to the height of .myDiv, but the position of .myDiv can,t remain fixed, it must be relative, then .myDiv2 will always stack at the bottom of the .myDiv, independent of its height.
Your html should be:

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 300px;
}

.myDiv2 {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  /* This now depends on the height of the first div */
}
```

```html
<h1>The div element</h1>
<div class="myDiv">
  <h2>This is a heading in a div 1 element</h2>
  <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv2">
  <h2>This is a heading in a div 2 element</h2>
  <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>
<p>This is some text outside the div element.</p>
```

MoreOver, you can view live example on my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Aqib_2000/pen/poRZBmN?editors=1100)

Comment: yeah i figured! Thanks for your input

Comment: Your welcome. Kindly upvote the answer if its helpful or solved your problem. happy Coding

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.myDiv {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;    
  text-align: center;
  position : relative;
  width : 100vw;
}
.myDiv2 {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;    
  text-align: center;
  width : 100vw;
  margin-top : 100px; <!-- This is fixed not dependent on First Div's Height-->
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The div element</h1>

<div class="myDiv">
  <h2>This is a heading in a div 1 element</h2>
  <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv2">
  <h2>This is a heading in a div 2 element</h2>
  <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

<p>This is some text outside the div element.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

or you can delete your style css "position:fixed" , this same result

Comment: Um, Thanks for your efforts but i want the first div to be fixed